# CSS background color not showing up unless I add overflow:hidden? Why?

Tags: css, background-color

I'm working on a CSS layout, but I don't understand why the background color of my navigation bar doesn't show up unless I add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS. Can someone explain to me what's going on? Thanks :)

My CSS file:

```css
@import "reset.css"; /* Meyer's CSS reset */

body { background-color: #f3f3f3;   font: 15px sans-serif; }

#wrapper { 
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
  width: inherit;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation li {
  float: left;
}

#navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Layout</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Nav0</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/HmteM/

Comment: @Ash - That's because he has `overflow: hidden` in the above code. See http://jsfiddle.net/tFQyT/

Comment: With `overflow: hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/tFQyT/1/

Comment: I would highly recommend a full `<link...>` tag to the `reset.css` vs. an `@import` statement.

Comment: @scunliffe: Why so? What's the difference?

Comment: Reason to not use @import http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/ (would have been 1 comment but I didn't edit it fast enough)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` causes the container to establish a new [formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) within which to contain the floats. Without it, the floated elements form their own formatting contexts and display independently of the container, out of normal flow.

Comment: @casey; as bolt said overflow: hidden helps the container to clear its inner floats because float force to an element out it's normal flow which have to clear it by it's parent element . **CHECK THIs** [LINK](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) **FOR MORE**

Answer (score 2):

You should use a clear fix class (either an empty element after the `<ul>` or use a clear fix class on the `<ul>` so the browser will properly clear the floats.

```
.clearfix {
    zoom:1;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Is one I use most of the time. Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gpQ2f/1/

Comment: Why *should* he use a clearfix class rather than `overflow: hidden/auto`?

Comment: It really doesn't matter unless the OP wants to use the features of overflow. Sorry my verbage had the wrong precision Bolt.